# findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode.: React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node

```
 import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';

    class HomeScreenCarousel extends Component {
        
             data= [{
                id:1,
                imgUrl:"https://www.iclarified.com/images/news/71027/71027/71027-1280.jpg"
              }];
            
             state={ 
                      carouselData:data
                   };
                    
              render() {
                        const {carouselData}=this.state;
                        return (
                            <div className="carousel-container">
                                <Carousel>
                                    {carouselData.map(
                                        item=>(
                                            <Carousel.Item key={item.id} interval={3000}>
                                                <div className="carousel">
                                                    <Link to="">
                                                        <img src={item.imgUrl}/>
                                                    </Link>
                                                </div>
                                            </Carousel.Item>
                                        )
                                    )}
                                </Carousel>
                            </div>
                        );}
```

Comment: The example given doesn't use `findDOMNode`? Or is that the issue?

Comment: Code is working fine, but in console i get the error findDOMNode

Comment: @user12596862 This will be because your carousel library uses `findDOMNode`, and in strict mode it gives a warning about that. You can check the React docs and google around to see what that function does and why it's warned against. Since the usage of `findDOMNode` is in the 3rd party code there's not a lot you can do, short of forking the carousel repo and updating the code. You can safely ignore this warning

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning. Just know that `react-bootstrap/Carousel` may not work in future versions of react which removes `findDOMNode`

Comment: oh got it ..thankyou